# Using ggplot to plot overall dataset and subsets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset organised into subcategories and sub-subcategories, along the lines of nested bullet points:

```
-1
 -1a
  -1ai
  -1aii
 -1b
  -1bi
```

...and so on.

I want to use ggplot2 to make a dotplot which shows all data for **1** followed by data for **1a** only, followed by data for **1ai** only, and so on.

Example dataset:

```
x <- data.frame(cat=1, subA=letters[rep(1:5,each=10)], 
subB=as.character(as.roman(rep(1:5,5,each=2))),value=rnorm(50,20,7))

> head(x)
  cat subA subB    value
1   1    a    I 26.75573
2   1    a    I 12.52218
3   1    a   II 24.53499
4   1    a   II 23.21012
5   1    a  III 11.18173
6   1    a  III 25.01914
```

I want to end up with a chart that looks something like this:

[image: subset and overall data dotplot]

I was able to make this plot by doing lots of subsetting and rbinding to make a massively redundant derivative data frame, but this seems like a clear example of Doing It Wrong.

```
x2 <- with(x,rbind(cbind(key="1",x), 
cbind(key="1 a",x[paste(cat,subA) == "1 a",]), 
cbind(key="1 a I",x[paste(cat,subA,subB) == "1 a I",]), 
cbind(key="1 a II",x[paste(cat,subA,subB) == "1 a II",])))

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
ggplot(x2,aes(x=reorder(key,desc(key)),y=value)) 
+ geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.1,height=0)) 
+ coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete("Category")
```

Is there a better way of doing this? A related problem is that it would be nice if each value always had the same amount of jitter added to it, whether it was plotted against "1" or "1 a" or "1 a II", but there I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to plot... but you can use `interaction` to get this effect... `ggplot(x, aes(x=value, y=interaction(cat, subA, subB))) + geom_point()`.  (also the function `desc` that you're calling in your plot step is not available to most of us.  Where is it from?

Comment: Interaction only seems to plot the results within their sub-subcategories (ie 1.a.i, 1.a.ii etc.) I want to show where values lie within the overall distribution as well as within the subcategories.

Comment: Whoops. That's from the plyr package. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Short of doing what @Arun has suggested... I would put it out there that using shape, size and/or color aesthetics may yield a much cleaner and clearer plot than your proposed visualization.  `ggplot(x, aes(x=value, y=interaction(cat, subA, subB), color=interaction(cat, subA), shape=factor(cat))) ...` or something.

Comment: Thanks! I think what I have above will make sense when I apply it to the actual data, but I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way other than reconstructing your data with separate groups as shown below:

```
x.m1 <- x[c("cat", "value")]
x.m2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, interaction(x[, 1:2])), function(y) {
    y$cat <- do.call(paste0, y[, 1:2])
    y[c("cat", "value")]
}))
x.m3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, interaction(x[, 1:3])), function(y) {
    y$cat <- do.call(paste0, y[, 1:3])
    y[c("cat", "value")]
}))

y <- rbind(x.m1, x.m2, x.m3)

ggplot(data = y, aes(x = value, y = cat)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2_multiple_levels]

**Note:** You should reorder the levels of `cat` column in `y` to order the y-axis in the way you want. I'll leave that to you.

**Edit:** Following @Justin's suggestion, you could do something like this:

```
x.m1 <- x
x.m1$grp <- x$cat
x.m2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, interaction(x[, 1:2])), function(y) {
    y$grp <- do.call(paste0, y[, 1:2])
    y
}))
x.m3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, interaction(x[, 1:3])), function(y) {
    y$grp <- do.call(paste0, y[, 1:3])
    y
}))

y <- rbind(x.m1, x.m2, x.m3)

ggplot(data = y, aes(x = value, y = grp)) + geom_point(aes(colour=subA, shape=subB))
```

[image: ggplot2_multiple_levels_color_shape]